# Typescript Compilation Error with React - Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

The original code used -

```
import { Create } from '@material-ui/icons';

<DroppableFolder
          count={draftsCount}
          sidebarOpen={open}
          folderId={FolderType.Drafts}
          Icon={Create}
          name="Drafts"
          type="folder"
          url={Communication.drafts}
/>
```

And this is the interface -

```
export default interface DroppableFolderProps {
  count?: number;
  folderId: string;
  label?: Label;
  Icon?: React.ComponentType;
  name?: string;
  type: LinkType;
  url: string;
  sidebarOpen?: boolean;
}
```

On replacing `Icon={Create}` with this React functional component,

```
const DraftIcon = <Icon icon="draft-icon" title="Draft Icon" size="medium" />;

<DroppableFolder
          count={draftsCount}
          sidebarOpen={open}
          folderId={FolderType.Drafts}
          Icon={DraftIcon}
          name="Drafts"
          type="folder"
          url={Communication.drafts}
/>
```

I get this error -

```
type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<{}, any> | FunctionComponent<{}> | undefined'.
  Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
    Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(props: { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | null'.
```

for the line `Icon={DraftIcon}`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, change the Icon property in DroppableFolderProps  to type IconProps

```
interface DroppableFolderProps{
  Icon:IconProps
}
```

Change the const DraftIcon to a functional component

```
const DraftIcon = ()=> <Icon icon="draft-icon" title="Draft Icon" size="medium" />;
```

And pass the DraftIcon to the DroppableFolderProps component

```
<DroppableFolder Icon={ <DraftIcon/> } />
```

Comment: Changing it to an arrow function worked - 

`const DraftIcon = ()=> <Icon icon="draft-icon" title="Draft Icon" size="medium" />;`
However, the rest of the code needs to be the same.
Thanks!